# How to implement an Escaper to prevent SQL Injection on Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, sql-injection

In my Spring Boot project I'm trying to implement a kind of virtual proxy able to intercept REST API coming from an external microservice and thus activate security filters to manage the following vulnerabilities: XSS, CSRF, SQL-INJECTION.
I was able to implement the filters concerning the first two vulnerabilities.
I am continuing on the SQL-Injection and for now I have implemented a class that behaves like Escaper (which I had already found here on stackoverflow) but I don't know if it's okay or if there is something better.

```
public class SQLInjectionEscaper {

private final DataSource dataSource = null;

public static String escapeString(String value) {
    StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder(value.length() * 11 / 10);

    int stringLength = value.length();

    for (int i = 0; i < stringLength; ++i) {
        char c = value.charAt(i);

        switch (c) {
        case 0: /* Must be escaped for 'mysql' */
            sBuilder.append('\\');
            sBuilder.append('0');
            break;

        case '\n': /* Must be escaped for logs */
            sBuilder.append('\\');
            sBuilder.append('n');
            break;

        case '\r':
            sBuilder.append('\\');
            sBuilder.append('r');
            break;

        case '\\':
            sBuilder.append('\\');
            sBuilder.append('\\');
            break;

        case '\'':
            sBuilder.append('\\');
            sBuilder.append('\'');
            break;

        case '"': /* Better safe than sorry */
//              if (escapeDoubleQuotes) {
//                  sBuilder.append('\\');
//              }

            sBuilder.append('"');
            break;

        case '\032': /* This gives problems on Win32 */
            sBuilder.append('\\');
            sBuilder.append('Z');
            break;

        case '\u00a5':
        case '\u20a9':
            // escape characters interpreted as backslash by mysql
            // fall through

        default:
            sBuilder.append(c);
        }
    }

    return sBuilder.toString();
}
}
```

In particular I would like to create an escaper similar to this but better and above all suitable for postgres db.
Can you help me?

Comment: How and for what do you intend to use that function? Why don't you use one of the existing tools?

Comment: can you tell me which tool are you referring to? I state that I cannot use Prepared Statement as I cannot have access to the starting microservice db

Comment: Huh? If you don't have database access, you have no SQL injection. PostgreSQL offers for example the `format` function.

Comment: And If I have db access how could I do?

Comment: As I said: that depends on what you are trying to do. SQL injection is not something that has to do with escaping a string, it is about constructing a statement from parts. Did you read up on the `format` function?

Comment: Have a look at https://jooq.org With this library you can write type safe SQL and jOOQ will care about creating prepared statements for you